# Error while building Android Apk using terminal Command

Tags: android, command-line

While building android application using command line I am getting this issue as shown below .How to get rid of this using command line.

```
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

How to remove this  -Xlint using command I am getting solution as gradle change

```
allprojects {
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}}
```

I am not able to get the command line . Please help me to find a solution thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to build again via command line.

This will give more information about which classes/methods are deprecated. This way, you can check and fix those warnings properly

Comment: Without using this in gradle there is no direct command line to achieve this